# Запятая перед "как" и ещё раз о согласовании сказуемого с однородыми подлежащими

Tags: пунктуация, согласование

Много раз читал о согласовании подлежащих и сказуемых, но всё равно остаются сомнения...

*Наверное, ему снились африканская ночь, полная звуков и запахов, и небо, чёрное как чернила с мириадами искорок звёзд.*

Нужно ли выделять запятыми "как чернила", или это можно отнести к устойчивому сочетанию?

Comment: Какое такое чернилО? Есть чернилА!

Comment: А запятая перед С? Обособленное определение (*чёрное как чернила*).

Comment: Ну так перед С запятая пропущена. Сейчас получается, что чернила с искорками звёзд.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Розенталя есть пример "*чёрный как сажа*".
http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=147

В сочетании "*чёрное как чернила*" ещё большая устойчивость, так как слова однокоренные.
В том, что можно не ставить запятую, сомнений не возникает. Но нужно учитавать несколько факторов:
1) наличие паузы перед КАК;
2) задумывается ли сравнение:
"*чёрное как чернИла*" обозначает цельное качество (*сильно чёрное*) — ударение на последнем слове;
или
"*чЁрное настолько, как чернила*" — сравнение, ударение на первом слове.

Про согласование:
У Розеталя читал, что при множественном числе подчёркивается, что в действии принимают участие несколько подлежащих (что снилось несколько вещей, а не одна). Здесь это не требуется. По смыслу понятно, что "*небо*" тоже относится к глаголу. Гораздо лучше звучит единственное число.

Здесь похоже на присоединительное значение: не `снились ночь и небо`, а `снилась ночь, и ещё небо`.

Comment: А где ответ? Где предложение, в котором запятые поставлены или не поставлены? Я вижу только рассуждения и комментарии, доводы за и против, вот только окончательного решения нет.

Comment: Я принял решение написать так:   "Наверное, ему снилась африканская ночь, полная звуков и запахов, и небо, чёрное как чернила, с мириадами звёзд".

Comment: *Чёрное настолько, как черлила* — звучит не по-русски.